# res/menu and res/xml are not there

Tags: android

When I try to create a new menu resource file in `res/menu` as stated in the guide, the folder is not there. Neither is `res/xml`. Can someone tell me how to solve this problem? I tried to create the folder but it didn't allow me to do so

Comment: Related post - [menu directory is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35121098/465053)

Answer (score 32):

If it is in android studio v2.1.1, to create a res/menu folder follow these steps:

Right click on `res` -> `New` -> `Android resource directory` -> Change the Resource type to 'menu' in the drop-down menu -> click OK

To create menu file under menu folder follow these steps:

Right click on menu folder -> `New` -> `Menu resource file` -> Give the file name -> click OK.

**Note**: For xml file it's the same procedure but in the dropdown menu choose 'xml' instead of 'menu'

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse? Right-click on the `res` folder, select `New` and then select `Folder`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create the folder with no issues. Check that you have write permissions on that folder. Also you can try to right click on the res folder and go to new then other. In the window that pops up select Android -> Android XML File. In the new window you can use the radio group to select what type of file you want to create. This should create the folders for you.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the res folder-->New-->Android reesource directory
There you can set Resource type: as "Menu" and add Menu XML as required.

Answer (score 1):

change the "Android" tag to "Project"
[image: change the "Android" tag to "Project"]

After doing that, find the Directory you created (manu)-> right click on the folder and choose "Menu Resource File"
[image: After doing that, find the Directory you created (manu)-> right click on the folder and choose "Menu Resource File"]
On the new Dialog change "Values" to "Menu -> press OK
[image: On the new Dialog change "Values" to "Menu -> press OK"]

Now you should see the "menu" folder in Android tag!