# menu directory is missing

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a very new programmer in Android. I'm trying to define an action overflow button in my app. From what I've read it involves modifying the `menu.xml` file.
I cannot find that file in my app and I don't have the `res > menu` directory.
I have created a SettingActivity. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Related post - [res/menu and res/xml are not there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8117236/465053)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can create a menu dir in the res/ folder. Right click on `res` in the project view in Android Studio and click new -> "Android Resource Directory". Then select menu under "Resource Type". You can then add a file to that new res/menu directory that contains your menu items like this (res/menu/main_menu.xml)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action"
        android:title="@string/action"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

And get sure to override the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` in the `MainActivity` class like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: When creating the project, the menu was created automatically by default before. But now it seems like google got rid of this - it doesn't include the code for menu anymore. Why? Is it possible to create the default menu by creating a new project?

Comment: I'm guessing they got rid of it because not everyone uses menu's and now creating these items (resource folders, asset folders, etc) inside Android Studio is easier. The default project should be as lean as possible and not include a bunch of unused folders/resources.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on res and you will android resource directory ->give directory name ->give resource type as menu : a menu folder will be created inside res, now right click on menu->new-> menu resource file->file name-> ok . Now you see the menu xml file inside res/menu/yourfile.xml

Answer (score 1):

just change the "android" to "project" in the top right-hand side of the android studio software.
[image: should change this option]

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the res in the Tools Window ->Select the Show in Explorer option.
If you have already created a menu directory and if it is hidden(or not shown) in the Tools Window, you can find it here.
If you have not created menu directory, you can use the the above answers to create it and add resource files to it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime when you create a menu resource directory then also it won't appear in the Android project view but it actually there, Since if it doesn't contain any file then the project indexing automatically hides it so to see that you just need to change from `Android` to  `Project Source files` like[image: this].

This answer may not be helpful to you but maybe for others who may experience the same type of problem.